# Spring ScheduledTasks not firing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to run a method in Spring with ScheduledTasks, so I have the following class:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);
    private static final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

    public void scheduleTaskWithFixedRate() {
    }

    public void scheduleTaskWithFixedDelay() {
    }

    public void scheduleTaskWithInitialDelay() {
    }

    public void scheduleTaskWithCronExpression() {
    }
}
```

And the following method in a different class

```
  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10 * 1000) //10 seconds
  public void taskThatRunsPeridically() {
      logger.info("Scheduled task method has been called ");
  }
```

But the method never runs, I've noticed thought that if I move the method to the Spring Boot Application class (the class that hosts `main`)

Why is this happening? How I can get schedule methods to run in wherever class that I add them?

Comment: are u sayinh if you put @Scheduled in Application class then it works? do u have `EnableScheduling` annotation somewhere?

Comment: Thank you, Yes, now I think because as @FidanBicaj said below, it would work in the class that has `@EnabledScheduling` which was the case in the main class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `@EnableScheduling` annotation in one of your Spring configuration classes or above the other class that contains your method, for example:

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public MySchdeduleClass {

      @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10 * 1000) //10 seconds
      public void taskThatRunsPeridically() {
          logger.info("Scheduled task method has been called ");
      }
}
```