# Spring Boot application run method periodically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am playing with a simple Spring Boot application and RabbitMQ.

However I cannot figure out how to run a method periodically.

Here is my Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApp {
    @Autowired
    Sender sender;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApp.class, args);
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void doSomethingAfterStartup() {
        sender.sendMessage();
    }
}
```

And the **sendMessage** method is defined as below

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 3000L)
public void sendMessage() {
    log.info("Sending message...");
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("my-exchange", "my-routing-key", "TEST MESSAGE");
}
```

However this method is called only once, I can see only a single line in the console.

What I missed in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring ScheduledTasks not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58361755/spring-scheduledtasks-not-firing)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you are missing [`@EnableScheduling`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html):

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApp {
    ...
}
```

Quoting the documentation:

> Enables Spring's scheduled task execution capability, similar to functionality found in Spring's `<task:*>` XML namespace. To be used on `@Configuration` classes as follows:
>
> ```java
> @Configuration
> @EnableScheduling
> public class AppConfig {
>
>      // various @Bean definitions
> }
> ```
>
> This enables detection of [`@Scheduled`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotations on any Spring-managed bean in the container.

Answer (score 0):

I am usually using the Spring `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`. You define it, as Bean for example then you wrap your method into a `Runnable` and you call it at intervals defined by a `CronTrigger`. The result can be retrieved using a `ScheduledFuture`

Check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler for a complete beginner tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative way if you don't want to rely on Spring's scheduler.

It's using rxjava2, here's an example:

```
@Component
public class MessagePublisher {

  Sender sender;
  Disposable d;

  @Autowired
  public Config(Sender sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
    this.d = doSomethingAfterStartup();
  }

  public Disposable doSomethingAfterStartup() {
    return Observable.interval(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe(tick -> {
      sender.sendMessage();
     });
  }

}
```